# How to use the "|" to append more than one list to an existing one?

Tags: elixir

I have this:

```
<%= for x <- [
  "a1.css",
  "a2.css",
  | List.wrap(assigns[:my_css])
  ] do %>
```

How I need to add one list of css files to it, without having to use `++`

But this won't compile:

```
<%= for x <- [
  "a1.css",
  "a2.css",
  | List.wrap(assigns[:my_css])
  | ["my_custom1.css", "my_custom2.css"] # won't compile
  ] do %>
```

How to fix it?

The order should remain as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` operator always builds `[single_item | existing_list]`.

You could always build up multiples lists: `["a1" | ["a2" | another_list]]` and get the resulting single list that you are looking for - but you're left trying to figure out which items are lists or not.

From your code example, it looks like you're trying to solve two problems though: build up a list of CSS file names, and then do something with each of them inside the `for` loop.

It would be common in Elixir to use `Enum.map()` or `Enum.reduce()` to do the same thing, without a for loop. (Hard to say without knowing your actual end goal.)

At the very least, you could simply do this two steps:

- build up the list of items you care bout
- then iterate over them with `for` or `Enum.map()`

```
# if everything was wrapped as a List already
css_files = Enum.concat([["a1.css"], List.wrap(assigns[:my_css]), ["b2.css", "b3.css"]])

# or, if it's not
css_files = List.flatten(["a1.css", ["c2.css", "c3.css"]])

# separately
for x <- css_files do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: will the order of the elements of the lists remain as is in the code?

Comment: how is `Enum.concat()` better or different from `++`?

Comment: Yes, the order of element will remain in both these versions.

Using `++` always requires an O(n) traversal to get to the end of the list; I suspect but am not certain that `Enum.concat()` will do the same thing, so it's no "faster" than `++` in that regard; it does allow concat'ing an arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't, you have to use `++` instead, so:

```elixir
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
[7, 8 | l1] ++ l2 # => [7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Longer answer - when you're using the `[|]` you're prepending items to a list. This can be done without changing the original list by creating a new list where the old list is a tail (it's an `O(1)` operation). But when you want to concatenate two lists, it cannot be achieved in this simple way - in order to preserve both original lists (which you have to do, because Elixir data is immutable) Elixir has to create a new list by prepending every item from one list to the other list, so it's an `O(n)` operation. Because of that, (I suspect) there is a different operator for this purpose.